# Show "Protected Internal" in UML?

Tags: c#, .net, uml

I am new to UML. I have found these symbols for showing different access modifiers in UML:

- `+` is for Public
- `-` is for Private
- `#` is for Protected
- `~` is for Internal

But in the reference that I consulted, there is no symbol for "Protected Internal."

Would the compound symbol `#~` be appropriate?

Comment: What reference did you consult? And to what UML diagram does your question apply? Wikipedia defines `~` to mean "Package" in its article about the [UML Class diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_diagram#Visibility).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unfortunately, there isn't a symbol (or combination of symbols) that means "Protected Internal." That is because the `internal` keyword is specific to C#, whereas UML was developed as a universal markup language. However, you can come to an agreement for using a particular symbol within your company.

Comment: Does your answer apply to the [UML Class diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_diagram#Visibility), or to a different UML diagram?

Comment: The answer applies to UML Class Diagram

Comment: I have also asked the OP as to whether his question is with respect to the UML class diagram. I presume so, but only the OP can clarify this.

Answer (score 2):

Not a beautiful solution, but you could also (ab)use a stereotype for it which you'd apply to the attributes/methods.